# Xml transfer via IPC for .net (4.0) to Mono on windows

Tags: c#, .net, mono, ipc, unity-game-engine

I have a .net 4.0 app computing data i'd like to visualise with www.unity3d.com which has c# mono scripting. To do this i'd like to send xml strings between the two apps - one of which is running .net and the other of which is running under mono.

I'm new to Interprocess communication but i think it's the way to go - does anyone know of a sample showing .net 4.0 to mono ipc?

any advice appreciated.

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think of it as "IPC". Use Web Services between the two. Use WCF on the .NET side. I don't know if Mono has support for WCF, but if not, WCF produces standard web services, so Mono should have no trouble consuming the WCF side.

Comment: Both programs will run on the same machine - will wcf still work?